# Remapping move_base Twist publisher topic

Tags: navigation, clearpath, jackal, topic-tools, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm working with a Clearpath Husky on ROS Indigo, Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to remap the topic that `move_base` publishes its Twist messages on to (`'cmd_vel'`) to another name that I can use with a `topic_tools` mux. I was able to do so by changing the `move_base.launch` file in the `jackal_navigation` package, however, I want to know if there's a way to do so without changing the source of the original package.

I created my own launch file that launches the `jackal_navigation amcl_navigation.launch` file and tried to remap the `move_base` publishing topic using `<remap from="cmd_vel" to="/new_cmd_vel"/>`, however, this did not work.

Are there any services or parameters that I am unaware of that remap the navigation stacks Twist message publisher?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Below is the launch file I am using and how I tried to remap the topic

```
<launch>
    <include file="$(find jackal_gazebo)/launch/jackal_world.launch">
        <arg name="config" value="front_laser"/>
    </include>
    <include file="$(find jackal_navigation)/launch/amcl_demo.launch">
        <arg name="map_file" value="/home/river/gazebo_map.yaml"/>
        <!-- This is how I tried to change it -->
        <remap from="cmd_vel" to="/nav_vel"/>
    </include>
    <include file="$(find jackal_viz)/launch/view_robot.launch">
        <arg name="config" value="localization"/>
    </include>
    <!-- How I would like to use my renamed topic (in a multiplexer) -->
    <node name="topic_tools_mux" pkg="topic_tools" type="mux" 
        args="/cmd_vel /bsc_jackal/bsc_vel /bsc_jackal/key_vel /bsc_jackal/nav_vel mux:=bsc_mux">
    </node> 
</launch>
```

Below is the modified source launch file for Jackal in `jackal_navigation/launch/include/move_base.launch`:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find jackal_navigation)/params/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find jackal_navigation)/params/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />

    <rosparam file="$(find jackal_navigation)/params/map_nav_params/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find jackal_navigation)/params/map_nav_params/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <rosparam file="$(find jackal_navigation)/params/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find jackal_navigation)/params/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <param name="base_global_planner" type="string" value="navfn/NavfnROS" />
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS"/>

    <remap from="odom" to="odometry/filtered" />
    <!-- Here is where I remapped the topic -->
    <remap from="cmd_vel" to="/bsc_jackal/nav_vel"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Below is the output of `rostopic list | grep vel` as Procopio requested. `/bsc_jackal/*` are the topics generated from the `topic_tools` mux. `/jackal_velocity_controller/cmd_vel` is just a relay to `/cmd_vel` using topic tools (I found this out by looking at the jackal source launch files).

```
/bsc_jackal/bsc_vel
/bsc_jackal/key_vel
/bsc_jackal/nav_vel
/cmd_vel
/jackal_velocity_controller/cmd_vel
/jackal_velocity_controller/odom
/navsat/fix/velocity/parameter_descriptions
/navsat/fix/velocity/parameter_updates
/navsat/vel
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281945/remapping-move_base-twist-publisher-topic./) by [piraka9011](https://answers.ros.org/users/27954/piraka9011/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2018-02-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-06**:
Can you paste your launch file here so we can see how you're attempting this?

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2018-02-12**:
paste the output of `rostopic list | grep vel` so we can see all the velocity related topics. It may be that they are inside some namespace.

**Comment by [piraka9011](https://answers.ros.org/users/27954/piraka9011/) on 2018-02-14**:
@Procopio please see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your first option worked, just copy the modified file to outside the original package and rename it as you like. Launch files do not need to be stored inside a package to work with it, it only contains instructions on what to launch, parameters, remaps, etc...

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2018-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piraka9011](https://answers.ros.org/users/27954/piraka9011/) on 2018-02-08**:
Since this launch file is being used by other packages, wouldn't I have to make sure that all the other packages can 'see' it? How would I tell the launch file to change its 'include' launch file?